# change date format iso-8601 to custom format

Tags: ios, swift4, dateformatter, jsondecoder

I have a json file being parsed using JSONDecoder(). However, I receive the variable timestamp of type Date in iso-8601-format ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX") but on my view, I want to display it in a custom format: "dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss".

I have written the following code, but I get nil for timestamp and furthermore I assume "date" is not the correct type to use when timestamp comes in iso-8601 format:

> Error json: typeMismatch(Swift.Double,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index
>   0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "timestamp", intValue:
>   nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a
>   string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

**swift4**

```
import UIKit

enum Type : String, Codable {
    case organizational, planning
}

// structure from json file
struct News: Codable{
    let type: Type
    let timestamp: Date //comes in json with ISO-8601-format
    let title: String
    let message: String

    enum  CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case type, timestamp, title, message}

    let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"  // change format ISO-8601 to dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss
        return formatter
    }()

    var dateString : String {
        return dateFormatter.string(from:timestamp) // take timestamp variable of type date and make it a string -> lable.text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are decoding a `Date` the decoder expects an UNIX timestamp (a `Double`) by default, this is what the error message tells you.

However you can indeed decode an ISO8601 string as `Date` if you add the `decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601` but this decodes only standard ISO8601 strings **without** milliseconds.

There are two options:

1. Add a `formatted` `dateDecodingStrategy` with a `DateFormatter`.

   ```
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"
   let decoder = JSONDecoder() 
   decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
   try decoder.decode(...
   ```
2. Declare `timestamp` as

   ```
   let timestamp: String
   ```

   and convert the string back and forth with two formatters or two date formats in `dateString`.

Comment: thanks for you help! Can you tell me where to add your solution 1) exactly? I put it into "let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {.." but it still doesn't work. I think I implemented it wrong...

Comment: Right before the `decode` line. I updated the answer.

Comment: Works like charme! Thanks a lot!